# "Cannot Register Duplicate Name" Namescope error in WPF

Tags: wpf

I've created a `TabItem` control with a particular structure(of `DataGrids` `Buttons` etc.). Some of the controls in the `TabItem` have names.This entire setup is created in the code-behind. Whenever a new tab is created, I clone this TabItem. The problem is that the names of the controls are registered with the namescope and when I clone these controls they cannot be re-registered.

I'm not sure what my options are here, but

1. Can I create a new namescope for each `TabItem`? Is that advisable? If so how can I find a particular namescope?
2. Can I register the control names with the parent control and not worry about changing namescopes?

What is my solution here?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing a bit more about what you are doing, it is hard to advise, but here are some thoughts ...

What are you using these names for? Could you use some other properties of your control instead, e.g. Tag?

Creating controls then cloning them sounds a bit nasty! Why not create a user control which contains all your controls? You can still create them in code-behind in the user control. This will solve your namescope issue, and also provide better structuring of your code!

Answer (score 0):

There is one method which you can use

```
public void UnregisterName(string name);
```